# Ignore ESLint rule in Uglify in Vue build script

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, eslint, uglifyjs

When I run `npm run build` I keep getting `punc` error in different lines.

Basically it is complaining about the way I'm declaring functions in my components:

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {}
}
</script>
```

If I just change it to

```
data: function(){}
```

it will work. But it's just too many places to change.

Is there a way to ignore `punc` in this case?

Comment: Because Uglify only supports ES5, do you add Babel to compile ES6 to ES5?

Comment: No i did not. It is just the basic configuration of vue-cli

Comment: So you will have to add babel!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using webpack. First of all get the most recent version of uglify and its webpack plugin

```
npm install uglify-es --save-dev
npm install uglifyjs-webpack-plugin --save-dev
```

then on your src/build folder search for the file with named "webpack.prod.conf.js"

at the end of the import statements add

```
var UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')
```

next override the plugin named "new webpack.optimize.uglifyjsplugin" with the following code

```
new UglifyJSPlugin({
  uglifyOptions: {
    parallel: {
      cache: true,
      workers: true
    },
    compress: {
      warnings: false,
    },
    output: {
      comments: false
    }
  },
  sourceMap: true
}),
```

this worked for me ;)